# edit variable in asynchronous while loop

Tags: bash

`a=0 while [condition]; do a=1 done & echo $a`
the normal ways like `done <<<$(test)` don't work because it's asynchronous.

I've tried using `<<<$(find tmp -type f)` `< <(find . -type f)` and`<<<$(test)` on it, but nothing seems to work. At most I get an error saying the file couldn't be found.

I'm just trying to get a to still be equal to 1 after the loop ends.

Comment: Is that a typo or the `;` in between `a=0` and `while` is missing.

Comment: Can you include some actual runnable code in your question? The example you've inluded doesn't make any sense. If I run `a=0; while [[ $a -lt 5 ]]; do ((a++)); a=8; done && echo $a` it seems to do what I expect.

Comment: Are you trying to set variables in the main shell process from a background subshell? If so, the answer is that you can't; each shell process has its own set of variables (and other shell state), and they cannot affect each other's internal state. You might have to have the background process write the value to a file, and the main one read it, or something like that. In any case, a clearer description of what you're trying to do (without *other* problems added, like your current example) would help.